# How to add a horizontal line in Column bar chart in Highcharts plugin?

Tags: plugins, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I want to add a horizontal line(red line)in the Column bar chart.[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by adding a `plotLine` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines)). Plot lines can be across the x-axis or y-axis, and in your case you need a line along the y-axis:

```
yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        value: 120,
        zIndex: 5
    }]
}
```

As you can see you can set color, width and the value the line will be at. Here `zIndex` is used to make the line come in front of the columns.

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/9o1tfL3w/) of it in use.